# Run a function per table row Angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs

I am creating a table with multiple rows and would like to call a function that will return a different response per row.

HTML:

```
      <div class="panel-body panel-scroll">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Host IP</th>
                    <th>DataCenter</th>
                    <th>Port</th>                        
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="personalDetail in personalDetails" required>
                    <td>{{ '{{personalDetail.address}}' }}</td>
                    <td>{{ '{{personalDetail.datacenter}}' }}</td>
                    <td>{{ '{{personalDetail.port}}' }}</td>
                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" ng-click="testMonitor(formParams.type,personalDetail.address,personalDetail.port,formParams.send,formParams.recv)">Test Monitor</button></td>
                    <td>{{ '{{ response }}' }}</td>
                </tr> 
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.testMonitor = function(type, host, port, send_string, recv_string) {
return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/dao/public/scripts/ItrcClass.php', {
    headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'text/html'
    },
    params: {
    type: type,
    host: host,
    port: port,
    send_string: send_string,
    recv_string: recv_string,
    }
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
    $scope.response = response.data;

    },function errorCallback(response) {
        $scope.response = response.data;
```

The response comes back correctly but it is not unique.  Ultimately, I would like each row to contain its unique response.

Comment: append it to `personalDetail`, e.g. `personalDetails[index].response = response.data` (pass the `$index` as a parameter)

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Can you elaborate a bit more on your suggestion?  I am still learning and not sure how to implement your suggestion.

Comment: extend the function to add the index as a parameter: `testMonitor(..., $index)`; add a property to the array object: `personalDetails[index].response = response.data;`; display it with `{{personalDetail.response}}`

Comment: additionally use `{{personalDetail.address}}` instead of `{{ '{{personalDetail.address}}' }}`. The error callback may not have `.data` property, set `personalDetails[index].response` to `null` instead

Comment: wow, thanks for the quick response!  That make more sense, I will give it a shot...